# Observable or async/await for NGRX selectors?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have an ngrx store and I'm calling the selector on ngOnInit (see below code). Somebody said that I should put this call in the async/await since I'm only waiting for one value. I am not sure if that is the right way because the observable calls its complete() function when the emit is done and since there's only one value it will immediately call complete(). Does anybody have a different opinion or a better approach? thank you.

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.store.pipe(select(selectSomeString), takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(
          (someString) => this.checkIfValid(someString)
        );
}

private checkIfValid(someString: string){
//some code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are only using the first emitted value, since you mentioned on the question that you are only waiting for one value.

In that case, I would recommend you to use the `take` operator after the `select` operator, and before the `takeUntil` operator.

```
this.store.pipe(
  select(selectSomeString), 
  takeUntil(this.destroy$))
.subscribe((someString) => 
  this.checkIfValid(someString)
);
```

Using `take(1)` will ensure that you take the 1st emitted value. You may read more about the operator [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/take).

Comment: There's only one value and not a stream of values. My selector is actually getting from the feature state which has the property. So I don't need to use take(1) operator right?

Comment: Yes, thats true, but it may emit multiple times. You can try adding some console.log() and see if that happens?

Answer (score 1):

Needing only one value is not a reason to wrap selectors in `async/await`.

NgRx is reactive by nature and utilizes RxJS heavily. RxJS provides enough operators to limit the number of events you take (e.g. `take(1)`). In your case, if the source only emits one value, then there's no reason to use any additional operators.

And there's no harm or risk in subscribing to an observable source if it only emits one value.

Just don't forget to unsubscribe from the subscription, otherwise it may lead to memory leaks.